# When should i cancel/kill a thread?

Tags: android

I created a Thread inside an Activity. At first, i thought that when `onDestroy()` is called on the Activity, then the thread will be killed also. But i was wrong. The Thread still continued running.

So i decided to cancel the thread inside the `onDestroy()` method. Everything works fine.

But there's 1 problem : `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called. For example : the Activity is killed abruptly by the OS.

So what's the best thing to do in this case ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should do everything related to cleanup in *onPause()*. You're correct that *onDestroy()* won't always be called, but *onPause()* is always called when activity moves to background or gets killed. But be careful to make your code in this method really lightweight, because an activity can't go to the background until this method returns.

Comment: I also thought about it, but if the activity's onPause() is called just because there's another Activity on top of it, it doesn't make sense to cancel the thread if the thread is downloading something.

Comment: When do you need to stop the thread exactly then? Maybe you need to download things in a service if you want the downloads to keep running after your activity is gone from the screen. If you're doing some background tasks, you shouldn't rely on the activity state.

Answer (score -2):

I would propose to place `Thread` killing in `Application` `onTerminate` method

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    MyThread myThread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        myThread=new MyThread();
        myThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate ()
    {
        super.onTerminate();
        myThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Be sure to declare MyApplication in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: -1: this information is misleading. From Android documentation on this method: "It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is executed when doing so".